# Why am I getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have a problem with the second app tutorial at [apple tut site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingMasterView/CustomizingMasterView.html). In the main class i get an error.

The code:

```
#import "birdwatchingAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([birdwatchingAppDelegate class]));
     } }
```

Error:

```
[birdwatchingViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector
sent to instance 0x6d37000'
```

The following is where the location of the error:

```
import "birdwatchingAppDelegate.h"
        #import "BirdSightingDataController.h"
        #import "birdwatchingViewController.h"

        @implementation birdwatchingAppDelegate

        @synthesize window = _window, dataController = _dataController, firstViewController = _firstViewController;

        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {
            UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
            birdwatchingViewController *firstViewController = (birdwatchingViewController *)[[navigationController
    viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

            BirdSightingDataController *aDataController = [[BirdSightingDataController alloc] init];
            firstViewController.dataController = aDataController;

            return YES;
        }
```

and the exact line that causes problems is:

```
birdwatchingViewController *firstViewController = (birdwatchingViewController *)[[navigationController
    viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
```

i can't locate the problem, can somebody help?

thanks..

EDIT:

By adding the NSlog i got following:

```
2012-02-10 11:24:06.059 Birdwatching[3057:f803] birdwatchingViewController
2012-02-10 11:24:06.060 Birdwatching[3057:f803] -[birdwatchingViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6878250
```

EDIT based on comment :

```
2012-02-10 11:51:20.696 Birdwatching[3152:f803] navi : <birdwatchingViewController: 0x6a49c20>
```

Comment: add this line before line with crash - NSLOG(@"%@", [[navigationController class] description]);

Comment: Please do yourself and may colleagues a favor and stick to the naming conventions: class names should start with uppercase characters, as in `BirdwatchingViewController` and `BirdwatchingAppDelegate`. The same is true for all custom types (like enums). Variables and methods should start with a lowercase character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because `self.window.rootViewController` is not a `UINavigationController` it might be simple `UIViewcontroller`

---

Edited based upon log
change your method to

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {
            birdwatchingViewController *firstViewController = (birdwatchingViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

            BirdSightingDataController *aDataController = [[BirdSightingDataController alloc] init];
            firstViewController.dataController = aDataController;

            return YES;
        }
```

Comment: print the description of `navigationController` object i.e. `NSLog(@"navi : %@", navigationController);` after `UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;` and post the log in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've just struggled with the same problem on this exercise for a while, and since the real answer was nowhere to be found I'll bump this question so that others can find it.

Besides the problem the op mentioned, I also had two other mysterious ones after starting over from scratch.
Every time the reason turned out to be that some value under "Utilities" was incorrect, even though I could have sworn I'd set it earlier!
If this happens to others, make sure `Class` (in Identity inspector) and `Identifier` (in Attribute inspector) still have the right values for your GUI objects, *after* you finish inputting all the code.

No idea if there is actually some unexpected behavior in Xcode where it doesn't save your values or silently reverts them later, or if it's just me being too new to this environment to keep track of what I do in it. :)